# ERC20 token balance is different from metamask

Tags: solidity, metamask

I created my test token with the following code

```
contract HackTokenA is ERC20("HACKA", "HACK"){
  constructor() {
    _mint(msg.sender, 1000)));
  }
}
```

after deployment to Rinkeby testnet, i import it to metamask , why it is showing me a balance of 0.000000000000001 instead of 1000 ? And the etherscan is also showing me a balance of 0.000000000000001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `decimals` . Just give it a read.

[https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20#:~:text=You'll%20probably%20want%20to,value%20of%2018%20for%20decimals%20](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20#:%7E:text=You%27ll%20probably%20want%20to,value%20of%2018%20for%20decimals%20).